# Do Salesforce Employee Communities work with the Salesforce1 app?

Tags: community

We are trying to implement [Employee community](http://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/community-cloud-faq.pdf?d=70130000000lzRiAAI).

I want to confirm if it supports (runs on) Salesforce1 as well? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, yes. You either will use the mobile browser or have to manually set up the endpoint as part of the login (on each device).

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-do-I-access-Salesforce-Communities-in-Salesforce1-and-what-are-the-differences&language=en_US